# Mixing keyword argument and arguments with default values duplicates the hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

So i discovered this ruby behaviour, which kept me going crazy for over an hour. When I pass a hash to a function which has a default value for hash AND a keyword argument, it seems like the reference doesn't get passed correctly. As soon as I take away the default value OR the keyword argument, the function behaves as expected. Am I missing some obvious ruby rule here?

```
def change_hash(h={}, rand: om)
  h['hey'] = true
end

k = {}
change_hash(k)
k
#=> {}
```

---

It works fine as soon as I take out the default or the keyword arg.

```
def change_hash(h, rand: om)
  h['hey'] = true
end

k = {}
change_hash(k)
k
#=> {'hey' => true}
```

---

```
def change_hash(h={})
  h['hey'] = true
end

k = {}
change_hash(k)
k
#=> {'hey' => true}
```

## EDIT

Thanks for your answers. Most of you pointed out that ruby parses the hash as a keyword argument in some cases. However, I am talking about the case when a hash has string keys. When I pass the hash, it seems like the value that gets passed is correct. But modifying the hash inside the function doesn't modify the original hash.

```
def change_hash(hash={}, another_arg: 300)
  puts "another_arg: #{another_arg}"
  puts "hash: #{hash}"
  hash['hey'] = 3
end

my_hash = {"o" => 3}
change_hash(my_hash)
puts my_hash
```

Prints out

```
another_arg: 300
hash: {"o"=>3}
{"o"=>3}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** ruby allows passing hash as a keyword argument as well as “expanded inplace hash.” Since `change_hash(rand: :om)` must be routed to keyword argument, so should `change_hash({rand: :om})` and, hence, `change_hash({})`.

---

Since ruby allows default arguments in any position, the parser takes care of default arguments in the first place. That means, that the default arguments are greedy and the most amount of defaults will take a place.

On the other hand, since ruby lacks pattern-matching feature for function clauses, parsing the given argument to decide whether it should be passed as double-splat or not would lead to huge performance penalties. Since the call with an explicit keyword argument (`change_hash(rand: :om)`) should definitely pass `:om` to keyword argument, and *we are allowed to pass an explicit hash `{rand: :om}`* as a keyword argument, Ruby has nothing to do but to accept *any* hash as a keyword argument.

---

Ruby will split the single hash argument between `hash` and `rand`:

```
k = {"a" => 42, rand: 42}
def change_hash(h={}, rand: :om)
  h[:foo] = 42
  puts h.inspect
end
change_hash(k);
puts k.inspect

#⇒ {"a"=>42, :foo=>42}
#⇒ {"a"=>42, :rand=>42}
```

That split feature requires the argument being *cloned* before passing. That is why the original hash is not being modified.

Comment: But why then it seems like I am getting correct values inside the function?
https://repl.it/repls/SafeCanineAndeancat

Comment: I am not sure I follow. What do you mean by “getting correct values”? In `repl` you are passing two arguments, there is no defaults.

Comment: oops sorry, wrong repl. updated https://repl.it/repls/SafeCanineAndeancat

Comment: I still doubt I follow. `hash` prints it’s default value, not the one you’ve passed in. Check it’s `__id__`.

Comment: from where i sit the hash printed out is the one i pass, not the default one :/ The id is different, yes which is i expect where the problem is. It seems like the hash is cloned behind the scenes.

Comment: @redFur in this case you passed a hash with string key `"o"`. Hashes with string keys are not interpreted as keyword arguments, thus Ruby was smart enough to pass it into first optional argument. If you change it to `my_hash = {o: 3}` you will get an `ArgumentError` (like in my answer below).

Comment: Ah that's it, thanks @AliakseiKliuchnikau . Why then the passed hash is unchanged after the function is executed?

Comment: @redFur, well, this is a bit unexpected behaviour - you found another interesting case - I will try to find the explanation

Comment: @AliakseiKliuchnikau thank you, I thought I was going crazy :) Everyone is rushing to point out the parsing-hash-as-a-keyword-argument thing. Which is correct, but the question goes further here.

Comment: oh wow haha, good job finding this out, pretty crazy. Thank you, I can sleep now.

Answer (score 1):

This is particularly tricky case in Ruby indeed.

In your example you have *optional argument* which is a hash and you have an *optional keyword argument* at the same time. In this situation if you pass only one hash, Ruby interprets it as a hash which contains keyword arguments. Here is the code to clarify:

```
change_hash({rand1: 'om'})
# ArgumentError: unknown keyword: rand1
```

To work around this you can pass two separate hashes into the method with second one (the one for keyword arguments) being empty:

```
def change_hash(h={}, rand: 'om')
  h['hey'] = true
end

k = {}
change_hash(k, {})
k
#=> {'hey' => true}
```

From the practical point of view it is better to avoid metdhod signature like that in production code, because it is very easy to make an error while using the method.